# Get warning about unused identifiers from use only

Tags: module, fortran, compiler-warnings, gfortran

Let's say I have the following code:

```
module test_mod
    implicit none
    private
    public :: A, B, double

    integer :: A, C
    integer, parameter :: B = 2

    contains

    integer elemental function double(n)
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        double = 2 * n
    end function
end module


program test_prog
    use test_mod, only: A, B, double
    implicit none

    A = 3
    write(*, *) A
end program
```

If I compile with `gfortran -Wall -Wextra` I correctly get warnings about:

- Unused variable `C` in test_mod.
- Imported but unused variable `B` in the program.

But I would like to also get a warning about the fact that `double` is imported, but unused.
Is there a compiler option that I overlook? Is there a compiler that does this?
Is it coming in later versions of gfortran? (I used 8.2.1)

Comment: I would even be interested in warnings for the general case of using modules (_without_ the explicit `only`).

Comment: @jack -Wuse-without-only for gfortran

Comment: @IanBush it is kind of what i was looking for but: what if one actually uses all public entities? will it still throw the error?

Comment: @jack Warning, not error, unless you also use -Werror. No it doesn't - but I think it is good style to always Use, Only as it documents which variables come from what modules